# C# - Can't insert decimal in AS400 DB2

Tags: c#, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying with a C# program to push data in my DB2 database. It is working fine for all fields except for one which is a DECIMAL(3,3), so value is between 0 to 1. I am reading an Excel file and when the value is `0.144`, in the database I see 0.001. If the value is `0.244`, it is going to be 0.002.

I am using the Oledb adapter.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandLine, connection);
for (int i = 2; i <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand(commandLine, connection);
    // Here, you set your parameters for a single row
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2CUS", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2LOC", worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null ? Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value) : "");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2CATG", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2CLAS", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2DESC", Regex.Replace(Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 5].Value), "[^\u0000-\u007F]", " "));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2MNRT", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2DYRT", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 7].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2WKRT", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 8].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2MORT", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 9].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2DSCP", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 10].Value));
    **command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2DWP", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 11].Value));**
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2CXCB", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 12].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2CXRT", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 13].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2STDT", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 14].Value));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("R2ENDT", Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 15].Value));
    cptRow += command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    pg2.Value = i * 100 / worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
}
pg2.Value = 100;
```

Comment: Why are you using `Convert.ToString` with a DECIMAL column?

Comment: Before putting your cell with the decimal value into a parameter for the command object, put it into a decimal variable and put that variable into the parameter.  Run your debugger and break at that assignment point and view the decimal variable--does it have the correct value?  If not, you found that your problem is in converting the cell value into a decimal, and not with your database.

Comment: When I'm converting into a decimal and check the debugger, the value is good.